# Appending parameters to PHP URL is not returning anything, but hard coded works perfectly

Tags: php, ios, json, parameter-passing

Alright, so here goes nothing.

the URL: http://tandemenvoy.michaeldvinci.com/forum/repliesJSON.php?rID=2 returns me absolutely nothing. if I hard code the SQL query to

```
"SELECT * FROM replies WHERE replyID = 2"
```

I get the correct JSON formatted request, but when I try passing it as a parameter in the URL. is just displays nothing -

now the reason I'm doing this is because I'm working on an iOS app that is transversing multiple tables and I need it to only display the matching 'replyTopic's to the 'categoryID's and I'm guessing if I can just append the categoryIDs to the end of the url with the correct query, it'll be a heck of a lot easier

**repliesJSON.php:**

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$rID = $GET_['rID'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM replies WHERE replyID = '".$rID."' ";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I would change `WHERE replyID = '".$rID."'` to  `WHERE replyID = '$rID'` in your sql statement

Comment: @MichaelDoye why? it is the same.

Comment: Sorry but `$sql = "SELECT * FROM replies WHERE replyID = '".$rID."' ";` is exactly the same as `$sql = "SELECT * FROM replies WHERE replyID = '$rID' ";` i dont know what you mean and how that change should fix it.

Comment: sorry, it actually outputs _'2'_ with the single quotes still there. This is because the statement is wrapped in double quotes, meaning php is already parsing for variables so when it gets to `'".$rID."'` it simply ignores the double quotes and concats the single quotes and the number 2.  Will post as an answer for future users @steven

Comment: @conedmiro i have posted the solution as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your Mysql statement is wrapped in double quotes, PHP will parse it for variables, meaning that `'".$rID."'` is outputted as **'2'** (with the single quotes still there) because PHP ignores the double quotes and concatenates the single quotation marks and the number 2.

Simply changing: `WHERE replyID = '".$rID."'` **to:** `WHERE replyID = '$rID'`  will fix this problem.

**Edit:**

you can also leave out the single quotes altogether as @steven has mentioned:

`WHERE replyID = $rID`

Comment: i dont want to bug you but by a given `$rID = 2;` in both cases will output `WHERE replyID = '2'`. I simply do not understand why this change will affect the result of the query. (by the way it should work without single quotes  so `WHERE replyID = $rID` should work, too as long $rID is an integer)

Comment: Yes it will work without single quotes as well. (PHP already parsing for vars) essentially, if affects the result of the query because it then ends up as `WHERE replyID = ''2''` (2 x single quotes).  [This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) might help.  This is simply my understanding of it from past experience. @steven

Answer (score 0):

```
$rID = $GET_['rID'];
```

should be

```
$rID = (int)$_GET['rID'];
```

The main error was the typo in your get var.
I additionally casted your getvar as integer because you are not using any prepare statments.

Comment: _$rID = (int)$_GET['rID'];
echo $rID;_ still shows nothing =/ thanks though

Comment: not based off an <a href> link - I want to just make the link and thought I coudl use the parameters in the url if they were instantiated in the php then use the resulting JSON to send through a JSONSerializedObject to pull the querey

Comment: maybe you should call the url first in your browser by hand to be shure to get the expected result. Please call the URL and do a `print_r($_GET);` at the beginning of your script.